# Append a int variable to a StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have this code

```
String str1 = (String) optionlist1.get(i);//str1=apple
String str2 = (String) optionlist2.get(i);//str2=mango
String str3 = (String) optionlist3.get(i);//str3=water

for(int k=1;k<4;k++){
   String str="str"+k;
   sb.append("<p>"+k+")"+str+"</p>");
}
```

When I print this I just get `str1,str2,str3` instead of the actual data i.e `apple,mango,water`.

Is there a way to do this ? Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: because you are print String str="str"+k; You are not using str1, str2,etc

Comment: Yes,I know it.But howw should I go round it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will not work since you are stating that `str = "str" + k`, which means that `str` will have values of `str1`, `str2`, etc. These values represent string literals, and not variable names. To go round your problem you can do this:

```
List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<String>();
fruit.add((String) optionlist1.get(i));
fruit.add((String) optionlist2.get(i));
fruit.add((String) optionlist3.get(i));

for(String str : fruit)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

What you are trying to achieve *is* possible through the [`Reflection API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) (more on that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/)), however I think that for your particular problem, using reflection might be a little bit overkill, so it might be better to stick with the easier solutions.

EDIT: This code should do what you are after through the use of reflection:

```
    public static List<String> lst0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> lst1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
    {

       lst0.add("abc");       
       lst1.add("def");

       Class thisClass = SOTest.class;
       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           Field field = thisClass.getField("lst" + i);
           List<String> lst = (List<String>) field.get(new ArrayList<String>());
           System.out.println(lst.get(0));
       }
    }
```

Comment: It almost worked..But the problem is  i have 9 options(in the question i have shown only 3),and if only 3 are filled,the rest of the 6 show null values when I display.Is there a way I can add the number of options i want?

Comment: @user3040563: What type of objects are `optionlist`? Are they Lists, JComboboxes?

Comment: Ok i will explain.I have many questions,each question has 9 options(some might be filled some might not be filled.in the above case 3 are filled).optionlist1 is a list,so is optionlist2.....optionlist9,all are lists.optionlist1.get(i)) gets the option1 of the first question(assuming i=1),similarly optionlist2.get(i) gets the  option2 of the first question and so on...

Comment: Ok i did it.check for not null or empty..thnkx

Comment: @user3040563: I have added reflection to my answer. Hope this sheds some light on your problem.

Comment: Yeah. Reflection is an ugly way to solve the problem. I'd strongly recommend following the first suggestion of just using a list or collection of some type.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot reference variables using their string literal because string "str1" is not equal to reference variable `str1`. One alternate approach can be to use an array as mentioned here:

```
    String strArrr[] = new String[3];

    String strArrr[0] = (String) optionlist1.get(i);//str1=apple
    String strArrr[1] = (String) optionlist2.get(i);//str2=mango
    String strArrr[2] = (String) optionlist3.get(i);//str3=water


    for(int k=1;k<4;k++){
    String str=strArr[k-1];
    sb.append("<p>"+k+")"+str+"</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A String by the name of `str1` is not the same as a String with the value of `str1`

e.g.

```
  String str1 = "Apple";

  str1.equals ("str1") == false;
```

try using an array

```
String str[] = new String [3];
str[0] = (String) optionlist1.get(i);//str1=apple
str[1] = (String) optionlist2.get(i);//str2=mango
str[2] = (String) optionlist3.get(i);//str3=water
```

and then

```
for(int k=1;k<4;k++){
    String s=str[k-1];
    sb.append("<p>"+k+")"+s+"</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable names cannot generate Dynamically.

You could try,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add((String) optionlist1.get(i));//str1=apple
list.add((String) optionlist2.get(i));//str2=mango
list.add((String) optionlist3.get(i));//str3=water

int counter=1;
for(String str : list){
sb.append("<p>"+counter+")"+str+"</p>");
counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

str1, str2 and str3 are variable names. You are creating variable names as a String str = "str" + k which is ultimately a value not variable name.

You need to create an array of String to store your options.

`String[] strs = new String[];`

You can add your str1, str2.. to this array.

`strs[0] = str1;
strs[1] = str2;
strs[2] = str3;`

and access this array in your for loop.

```
for(int k=0; k < 3; k++) { 
    String str="str"+k;
    sb.append("<p>"+ strs[k] + "</p>");
}
```

This will work. :)